# Optimal way to have a 2D array wrapper in C#

Tags: c#, c, arrays

A little background to start: Our software involves a C calculation engine wrapped with C# and then a C# WPF GUI on top of that. We have structures in the C and then object versions of them in the C#.

One issue I have run into is that one of our structures in the C is defined like this:

```
struct mailbox
{
    char  string[15][256];
    float number[500];
}
```

We have many structs with arrays, and those are fine, but the 2D char array is tripping me up. Our usual practice is to have a matching C# struct definition, and then an object that takes that and wraps the fields with properties, as well as lots of other functionality. The current way I have achieved this is by making two structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct Character256String
{

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    private char[] __value;

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return new string(__value);
        }
        set
        {
            this.__value = (EngineUtils.FillOrTruncate(value, 256)).ToCharArray();
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Character256String source)
    {
        return source.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Character256String(string source)
    {
        return new Character256String
        {
            Value = source
        };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return new string(__value).ToString();
    }
}

public struct MailboxStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Mailbox.MailboxMaxStrings)]
    public Character256String[] strings;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Mailbox.MailboxMaxNumbers)]
    public Single[] numbers;

}
```

Finally, the actual `Mailbox` C# object has an instance of the `MailboxStruct` and properties for `Strings` and `Numbers` that wrap the struct's versions. Everything is mostly working, the issue I am having is that if I make the object's `Strings` property a `Character256String[]` then it can persist values but looks ugly and isn't a standard type. If I make it instead a `string[]` and basically create a `string[]` from the struct's `Character256String[]` in get, then if you set a value in the array it won't persist since this is doesn't connect to the original instance of the array.

Long story short, in the `Mailbox`object, I want to be able to do code like so:

```
Mailbox mailbox = Magic.GetMailbox(); // Gets the value from the C
mailbox.Strings[0] = "This is a test";
mailbox.Save(); // persists the value back to the C
```

I can't figure out a nice way to make `Mailbox.Strings` a `string[]` but still persist the values. What makes this complicated, and why this isn't an issue with a 2D `int` array for example, is that I am getting char arrays from the C and have to wrap them to make them strings. This is actually necessary, as our C "strings" are all fixed length char arrays so we need to pad or truncate the values when they are set.

Hopefully this is clear... Sorry about the class names. I removed product identifying names and was left with some pretty lame results.

Comment: So you're saying that it works fine if you use a Character256String but you don't like using it?

Comment: Yes it "works fine" as in I can set the value and it persists but then I have to expose this structure. While the implicit operators help (i.e. I can set it like a string) it still isn't an actual string. Also, we have a few of these of different sizes so I need to make a different wrapper structure for each one.

I thought about trying to just flatten the array into one `char[15 * 256]` and making a string wrapper for it that would do indexing but that would have the same persistence issue where getting the value in order to set it would give a new object instance.

Comment: The implicit string conversion doesn't take place unless it's actually used, so if I just do `mailbox.Strings[0]` I will get the `Character256String` object:
`<foo.Character256String object at 0x000000000000002B [This is a test      (lots of blank spaces)]>`
But if I use that result in code I can treat it like a string and then the implicit string operator is called. So for example if using IronPython I call `print (str.strip(mailbox.Strings[0]))` the input to `str.strip()` is of course a string and it works as one and calls that operator (confirmed with breakpoints).